# Windows.event is undefined -Javascript error in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onmouseover

I'm using javascript to change some settings of asp button on mouseover. It is working in IE. But not working in Firefox. Is there any other javascript code that will support almost all browsers? My code is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var previousColor;
        function Changecolor() {
            previousColor = window.event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor;
            window.event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = "Blue";
            window.event.srcElement.style.cursor = "hand";
        }
        function RestoreColor() {
            window.event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = previousColor;
        }
</script>


<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" BackColor="#800000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" onmouseover="Changecolor();" onmouseout="RestoreColor();" ForeColor="White" Height="28px" OnClick="btnSearch_Click2" Text="Search Jobz" Width="117px" />
```

Comment: Why are you making it so difficult? Just use CSS.

Comment: Indeed, CSS is better for this sort of thing, although `:hover` won't work in IE6 without [whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the Mozilla Developer Center docs on [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event).  In Internet Explorer, the global event object is created when an event is fired.  In standards compliant browsers, the event object is passed as the first argument of the function assigned to the firing event.  If your event is defined in the HTML, the event object is created under the variable name `event` and can be passed to the functions you're calling.

Also note that the `event.srcElement` property is IE only and most other browsers use `event.target` instead.

Taking this into consideration, your function should look like this:

```
<script>
        var previousColor; 
        function Changecolor(evt) {
            var srcEl = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
            previousColor = srcEl.style.backgroundColor; 
            srcEl.style.backgroundColor = "Blue"; 
            srcEl.style.cursor = "pointer"; 
        } 
        function RestoreColor(evt) {
            var srcEl = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
            srcEl.style.backgroundColor = previousColor; 
        } 
</script> 


<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" BackColor="#800000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" onmouseover="Changecolor(event);" onmouseout="RestoreColor(event);" ForeColor="White" Height="28px" OnClick="btnSearch_Click2" Text="Search Jobz" Width="117px" />
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working.. But, cursor is not working.. I can't see the hand symbol both in Google Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Ok.. I used "pointer" instead of "hand".. Now it is working for me :-) Thanks a lot...

Comment: Ahh you beat me to it.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use CSS (with its `:hover` pseudoclass) instead of JS?

But if you need to use JS for some reasons just pass reference to the element as function parameter:

```
function Cangecolor(ref){
  prevousColor = ref.style....;

...

onmouseover="changecolor(this)"
```

Right now your code doesn't work because IE uses different Event Model (good browsers uses W3C Event Model, but IE uses its own). You can read about W3C/IE event models at: [How to equalize the IE and W3C event models](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/127-how-to-equalize-the-ie-and-w3c-event-models/)]

Comment: The `:hover` pseudo-class doesn't work on elements other than `<a>` in IE 6.

Comment: If you have to care about IE6 then use [whatever:hover](http://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&q=whatever:hover&btnG=Szukaj+w+Google&lr=) or even better [IE8.js](http://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&q=IE8.js&btnG=Szukaj&lr=&aq=f&oq=)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bother with the event object. Also, the correct value for the cursor CSS property is "pointer" rather than the IE-specific "hand", unless you need to support IE 5 or 5.5.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var previousColor;

        function changeColor(el) {
            var s = el.style;
            previousColor = s.backgroundColor;
            s.backgroundColor = "Blue";
            s.cursor = "pointer";
        }
        function restoreColor(el) {
            el.style.backgroundColor = previousColor;
        }
</script>


<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" BackColor="#800000"
    Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial"
    onmouseover="changeColor(this);" onmouseout="restoreColor(this);"
    ForeColor="White" Height="28px" OnClick="btnSearch_Click2"
    Text="Search Jobz" Width="117px" />
```

Comment: Not for the code specified in his question, but I thought I'd include the event object in my answer just in case his sample was a simplified version of a bigger portion of code as is often the case :) +1

Comment: @Andy E: agreed, and I may have done the same had you not already done so.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same (window.event in firefox) problem with below code.

```
<html>
<body onkeyup="fClosePop();">
</body>
<script language="javascript">
  function fClosePop(){
        var e= (window.event)?event.keyCode:evt.which;  
        if( e.keyCode ==27)
        {
            try
            {
                alert(1);
            }
            catch(e)
            {

            }
        }      
    } 
</script>
</html>
```

Then I tried to tweak the code and found the solution below.
I have just passed the event from the function.

```
<html>
<body onkeyup="fClosePop(even);">
</body>
<script language="javascript">
  function fClosePop(e){
           if( e.keyCode ==27)
           {
                      try
                      {
                       alert(1)
                       }
                      catch(e)
                      {

                      }
            }      
    } 
</script>
</html>
```

I hope this will be helpful to you.