# Event.ClientX is not working in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript

I have coding which is working in IE but not in firefox and chrome...

```
 function handleWindowClose() {
            if ((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY < 0))
             {
                 event.returnValue = "Are You sure to leave this page";
             }
         }
         window.onbeforeunload = handleWindowClose;
```

Can anyone help me...

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116177/windows-event-is-undefined-javascript-error-in-firefox

Answer (score 8):

`window.event` is a IE-only thing. 
To get it to work in other browsers you have to get the event as an argument of the handler function:

```
function handleWindowClose(e) {
    e = window.event || e; 
        if ((e.clientX < 0) || (e.clientY < 0))
        {
            e.returnValue = "Are You sure to leave this page";
        }
}
window.onbeforeunload = handleWindowClose;
```

Comment: window.event is also supported by chrome safari and opera.

Comment: Don't forget to add window scrollLeft and window scrollTop if you're positioning an item.

Answer (score 1):

maybe just add mousemove handler that will store mouse position in variable

```
var mouse;
function storeMouse(e)
{
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    mouse = {clientX: e.clientX, clientX:e.clientY};
}
function test(e){
     alert(mouse.clientX);
}
```

and use jquery?

```
  $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    if (iWantTo) {
        return 'Are You sure to leave this page';
    }
});
```